# Android Youtube Player error while playing private videos

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

Android Youtube player cue works perfectly fo public videos but throws an error for privately uploaded youtube videos. Didn't find any solution anywhere.

**YOUTUBE API PLAYER VERSION:** 1.2.2

```
2020-07-07 16:52:02.225 21134-24178/? E/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: Problem fetching WatchNext response
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: aajk: Unknown error.
    at apxi.a(PG:135)
    at apxi.get(PG:91)
    at alem.b(PG:24)
    at alem.run(PG:43)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at zkm.run(PG:13)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
 Caused by: aajk: Unknown error.
    at acdb.c(PG:106)
    at zup.a(PG:62)
    at zto.run(Unknown Source:17)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
    at zkm.run(PG:13) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
 Caused by: bsw
    at zto.run(Unknown Source:13)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
    at zkm.run(PG:13) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
2020-07-07 16:52:02.226 21134-21134/? E/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: Unhandled ErrorReason in onError
```